# Tempest Cleric, if your attack hits with Booming Blade and Divine Strike, can your channel divinity max both damage rolls?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric

The Tempest Domain's channel divinity says

> When you roll lightning or thunder damage, you can use your Channel
>   Divinity to deal maximum damage, instead of rolling.

but doesn't specify that you can only apply that to one roll of damage or all rolls if they happen at the same time

If multiple instances of possible damage hits an enemy (like say lightning from Absorb Elements, thunder from Divine strike and more thunder 1d8+2d8 from an opportunity attack Booming Blade allowed by War Caster), can you channel divinity to deal maximum damage from all of them, or only one of them?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast the question is only in the body of the post and the title must match the body. If OP wants to ask about booming blade they should [edit] that into their body. As it is, the title now reflects the actual question being asked and not a hypothetical potential question they might want to ask. That is my understanding for how things are normally done, so I have reimplemented the previous edit. It appears OP removed the booming blade part from the body but forgot to remove it from the title to me.

Comment: @guess can you please clarify what spell you want to be asked about here? Is it booming blade or absorb elements? You had one in your title and one in your body. Here at RPG.se only the question asked in the body matters and the title is only a summary of it, and I see you removed the booming blade part in a past revision.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Rolled back, we can start again when guess returns.

Comment: I'm putting this on hold so that we can get some confirmation about the nature of the question before we proceed further.

Comment: @NautArch Why not the original? That's waht the answer currently covers.

Comment: @NautArch The problem with that is that the answer was based on the original question: and that answering also takes time, overlap, etc.  Hold for clarification remains the better idea.

Comment: @NautArch We should leave the current revision up. Not because of the qualities of any specific revision, but because getting some clarification before we proceed further also means “let's stop messing around with revising this thing before we get a word in from the OP”. The OP can review the revision history, and right now rolling back would do nothing useful and add clutter to that history. (In this kind of situation I'd switch revision only if the current revision was far worse than other options due to e.g. vandalism or inappropriate edits.)

Comment: @NautArch Revisions don't get put on hold, questions do. This question is on hold. Guess needs to clarify to us what they're actually after. Then we revise, then the question comes off hold.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### All of them

Since the text refers to maxing out a damage roll, then both Booming Blade and Divine Strike, (and Absorb Elements if a charge of that is available) damages dice should max out.

The idea behind this answer is that since all of the dice being rolled to apply thunder or lightning damage are linked to *a single weapon attack*, they are all one damage roll. (Similar mechanically to sneak attack dice being added to a single attack for a Rogue).

- FWIW, dev Jeremy Crawford [tweeted about this if you find those tweets useful](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/04/22/green-flame-blade-hex-divine-smite-how-many-damage-rolls-are-there/):

  > When something in the game (Sneak Attack, Divine Smite, hex, etc.)
  >   causes your attack/spell/etc. to deal extra dice of damage, those dice
  >   are added to the damage the effect is already dealing, if any. It's
  >   one big damage roll, extra damage included.

#### Reasoning behind this answer.

The question to resolve is whether all of the damage is rolled at once, or if there are separate rolls.  With separate rolls, one could argue that one only applies it to one.  But if you roll all dice at the same time, there is no reason not to apply "max" to the total roll for that one attack.

> Divine Strike
>   ... Once on each of your turns *when you **hit** a creature with a weapon Attack*, you can cause the Attack to deal an extra 1d8 thunder damage to the target.

Did you make a weapon attack?  Yes.
Part the *booming blade* cantrip is the making of a weapon attack. (You still have to hit if you desire Divine Strike damage).

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell's range, otherwise the spell fails.

The d8 from Divine Strike is rolled in addition to the roll from *booming blade*. (And the weapon).

> Channel Divinity: Destructive Wrath
>   ... **When you roll lightning or thunder damage**, you can use your Channel Divinity to deal maximum damage, instead of rolling.

You made a weapon attack, you rolled various dice for thunder damage, max the entire roll.  You have now used that instance of your channel divinity.   If you have some stored lighting from Absorb Elements, the "lightning or thunder" text allows that to be added to the damage on that attack, and maxed as an eligible damage type for that use of channel divinity for that one weapon attack.

---

I can see a DM calling them out as "separate rolls" but at our tables, we tend to roll all of the damage at once to keep play moving.

This gets a little tricky with Booming Blade in particular, since the damage from the "when the target moves" feature typically happens at a later time when the target you hit moves ... which could be during its turn or even during a subsequent round.

1. The simplest way to deal with this is to max that damage once the
   targer moves because it is *explicitly linked to the particular
   attack that used the Channel Divinity class feature* (which is a
   short rest resource, and thus not spammable round after round).
2. With that said, @Seidr makes the point that a ruling for a separate,
   and not maxed, movement-boom-damage roll [comes from deeper in that
   tweet stream](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/04/22/green-flame-blade-hex-divine-smite-how-many-damage-rolls-are-there/), if you assume that "other processes" is what that
   movement is.

   > @JeremyECrawford
   >   Separate damage rolls are delivered by separate attack rolls, saving throws, or other processes.  Extra/bonus/additional damage is called extra/bonus/additional damage.
   >
   > @RubiksMoose Replying to @JeremyECrawford
   >   how do you distinguish between second damage roll and extra damage?

   While I give preference to that class feature since it is a limited use resource (my "specific over general" for this case) it would be worth discussing this element of the question with your DM to see what makes the most sense at your table if you expect to use this combo in play.  The other approach makes sense if you feel that the intent of "other processes" includes that movement.

Comment: [Jeremy Crawford](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/04/22/green-flame-blade-hex-divine-smite-how-many-damage-rolls-are-there/) has clarified about damage rolls and secondary effects already, which indicates that the secondary effect of Booming Blade would be a separate damage roll

Comment: @Seidr That's not how it reads to me, though the other point supports my answer. Thank you. :)   *When something in the game (Sneak Attack, Divine Smite, hex, etc.) causes your attack/spell/etc. to deal extra dice of damage, those dice are added to the damage the effect is already dealing, if any. It's one big damage roll, extra damage included. #DnD* FWIW, that isn't in the Sage Advice Compendium, so it's not official SA. [On page 15 of SA Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=15) ... nothing there.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Further down he goes on to clarify "If an attack has a damage roll but also a second damage roll (not extra damage) that is contingent on a saving throw, the damage of that second source is a different damage roll from the first. #DnD" and "Separate damage rolls are delivered by separate attack rolls, saving throws, or other processes. Extra/bonus/additional damage is called extra/bonus/additional damage. #DnD". And while it may not be an entry in the official SA, it does provide further insight into how the mechanics would work in this situation

Comment: @Seidr: What SA Compendium says about it is: *When a cleric uses the Destructive Wrath feature, does it maximize all damage getting rolled, as long as some of it is lightning or  thunder? Destructive Wrath is meant to maximize lightning and thunder damage only* Hmm, my display stopped scrolling before that, I'll check again, but there isn't a save against this damage. *that is contingent on a saving throw,* Also, it isn't a separate attack roll. The booming blade attacker had to hit in the first place for any of that to work.   *scratching head now*

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Specifically "Separate damage rolls are delivered by separate attack rolls, saving throws, or other processes." The other process would be the creature moving before the effect wears off causing another damage roll.

Comment: @Seidr Thanks for your persistence, I added that point in the end.  "Other processes" also takes interpretation ...